# Fatal Wordpress Error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array in

Tags: php, reactjs, wordpress

I just started receiving this error. No idea how this happened as I have updates turned off. Code is below:

```
// Convert json to php array.
$files_data = json_decode($request['body']);
if($files_data === null)
    return ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are getting an instance of WP_Error in $request['body']. You can patch your code like so...

```
<?php

$files_data = !is_wp_error($request['body']) ? json_decode($request['body']) : null;
if($files_data === null)
    return ;
```

But you should really look in to the WP_Error error and fix that.